# Django gives NoReverseMatch error after changes to urlpattern

Tags: python, django

In my templates I put urls for text article objects like this:
`<a href="{{texto.get_absolute_url}}">Text</a>` where `get_absolute_url` method for my text model objects is defined in the `models.py` like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('viva.views.texto_completo', kwargs = {'anno': self.fecha_cr.strftime('%Y'),
                                                         'mes': self.fecha_cr.strftime('%m'),
                                                         'dia': self.fecha_cr.strftime('%d'),
                                                         'slug': self.slug})
```

and the related urlpattern in the `urls.py` is like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<anno>\d{{4}})/(?P<mes>\d{{2}})/(?P<dia>\d{{2}})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', texto_completo),
)
```

Django gives me a NoReverseMatch error:

```
Reverse for 'viva.views.texto_completo' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'anno': '2015', 'dia': '12', 'mes': '06', 'slug': u'jacarandas-walk-johannesburgo'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<anno>\\d{{4}})/(?P<mes>\\d{{2}})/(?P<dia>\\d{{2}})/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)']
```

This seems strange, because previous version worked perfectly. In the **working version** `get_absolute_url` was defined as:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    some logic to figure out 'tema' value
    ...
    return reverse('viva.views.texto_completo', kwargs = {'tema': tema,
                                                         'anno': self.fecha_cr.strftime('%Y'),
                                                         'mes': self.fecha_cr.strftime('%m'),
                                                         'dia': self.fecha_cr.strftime('%d'),
                                                         'slug': self.slug})
```

and the pattern was like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<tema>[-\w]{{1,{l1}}})/(?P<anno>\d{{4}})/(?P<mes>\d{{2}})/(?P<dia>\d{{2}})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'.format(l1=settings.MAX_LENGTH_TEMA), texto_completo),
)
```

Now I can't seem to get the new version to work. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not using `.format` anymore, you don't need to escape curly braces:

```
^(?P<anno>\d{4})/(?P<mes>\d{2})/(?P<dia>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$
```